# Ajax response returns HTML of the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I'm trying to dynamically populate a gridview when the user presses the load more button, without refreshing the page.

The problem I'm facing is that the response returns the HTML of the page it was sent on. Upon further debugging I think the function is not called at all, but I went through dozens of questions and tried multiple ways to include the URL with/without razor, none of which seem to work.

This is my ajax code which I've been using to test this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '@Url.Action("ProcessLogEntries", "MediaFiles")',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: successFunc,
    error: errorFunc
});

function successFunc(data, status) {     
    alert(data);
}
```

And this is the function in the controller I'm trying to call. I've tried with `[HttpGet]` as well. Still the same.

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public ActionResult ProcessLogEntries()
{
    return Json(new { isSuccess = "hello" });
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: One simple way before debugging whats wrong with the Jquery Ajax code is to test the method with Postman/Fiddler to find the actual problem, If it is returning the desired response then we can go with finding bugs in code

Comment: Can you please attached that HTML response?

Comment: The HTML response sometimes is the .NET error page containing the details of the error, so if you review that, it may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `[WebMethod]` decorator you need to make your method static, and given your example, this is another example of how you could call it on the client-side:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "PageName.aspx/MethodName",
  data: "{}",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(msg) {
    // Do something interesting with msg.d here.
  }
});
```

If you're using MVC you can replace the url parameter with something like:

```
url: "MediaFiles/ProcessLogEntries"
```

Answer (score 0):

For MVC, you don't want to use WebMethod attribute; you want to use:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult ProcessLogEntries()
{
    return Json(new { isSuccess = "hello" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Adding the "AllowGet" setting makes sure the system doesn't throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Can you remove this method attribute and try it. 
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]

This is not required when your are calling in the mvc apps.